# Changing the Domain for Wordpress Install

Tags: wordpress, dns, nameservers

I have a domain, www.mysite.com, which is registered at NETWORK SOLUTIONS, LLC. and currently points to a hosted page at a 3rd party.

I have created a new wordpress page on Hostgator, and I created it using the domain www.mysite.biz.

I want to now point www.mysite.com to the new page on hostgator but without redirecting.

I believe what I need to do is:

- change the www record on Network Solutions to the IP address on Hostgator.
- I believe There is a plugin I can us to change the domain for all of the wordpress database.

Are these the correct steps? What is the plugin name I can use to change the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin I've used to change a domain name in wordpress. https://wordpress.org/plugins/go-live-update-urls/

When you say you want to point www.mysite.com to your new wordpress site "without redirecting", are you saying you want to use www.mysite.com as the new domain name? If so, you're going to want to go into your account with NETWORK SOLUTIONS, LLC and enter in hostgator's nameservers. See here: [Network Solution Link](http://www.networksolutions.com/support/move-dns-to-a-new-server/) and here: [Hostgator Link](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/employees/what-are-my-name-servers)

Comment: Yes I am just making sure I am doing this the right way. I don't do this very often. 

The old site is using .com and I didn't want that to go away until the new site was ready so I built the new site on .biz but now that the page is ready I want the new site to be .com.

So am I correct in the process - Point the URL to the host gator nameservers and then I need to update the hostgator wordpress page to change the url everywhere. Right?

Comment: Is this process possible with Network Solutions and hostgator by using the A record instead of the nameservers?

Comment: Yes, you could do that as well. But if hostgator decides to change the IP address your site would be down until you updated the A record. So unless you purchased a static IP, I would use go with the nameservers.